# Getting data from two tables with condition SQL

Tags: sql, mariadb

I need help with SQL query. I've been trying to figure it out for a week.

I need it to get data from both tables, but if the date and sport are the same as in the second table, the data will only be taken from the first table.

Each table can have 4 sports with the ID from the connected table.

So the date can be the same 4 times, but each time with a different sport.
That means if in the first table the date is 2020-01-01 and sport is ID 1 and in the second table the date is 2020-01-01 and sport ID 2 the data will be taken from both tables.
But if in the first table the date is 2020-01-01 and sport ID 1 and in the second table the date is 2020-01-01 and sport ID 1, the data is taken only from the first table.

Is it possible to do it somehow? I will be happy for any idea. Thank you!

I use MariaDB. First table is named reservation and second one reservation_r.

[image: table1]
[image: table2]

**Example with result:**

[image]

Comment: Also showing us the expected output from this sample data would help your question.

Comment: In this case, it shows all the data only from the first table. Because the date and sport are the same in both tables. If the sport in second table is ID 2 or something except 1 it shows all data including the second table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `union all` with some filtering:

```
select r.*
from reservation r
union all
select rr.*
from reservation_r rr
where not exists (select 1
                  from reservation r
                  where r.customer_idcustomer = rr.customer_idcustomer and
                        r.date = rr.date and
                        r.sport_idsport = rr.sport_idsport
                 );
```

Comment: I don't know what 'r' means. In fact, this is probably quite complicated for me :-D. In any case output is: Table 'reservation_rr' doesn't exist. I'm sorry, I'm a beginner trying to understand more complex queries.

Comment: @RadimNěmeček . . . It is a table alias which is a basic part of SQL.

Comment: I found out something about aliases. But this aquery still doesn't work. Some idea? :(

Comment: I found out where the problem was. It works, it was just a badly named column. Thank you!